# How can you work with dates on Android/Kotlin with minSDK = 21?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to find the difference between two dates (in milliseconds) and all the date/time related functions require API 26.

```
private var timerStartTime: LocalDateTime? = null
val now = now()

[...]

if () {
} else if (now.nano - timerStartTime!!.nano <= 800000000) {
}
```

Comment: `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` have been around since API Level 1. Create two `Calendar` objects representing your two dates, call `getTimeInMillis()` on each, and subtract them to find the difference in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can't - those Java 8 APIs aren't available on those lower API levels. There are a couple of backports available, however, for example [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).